# Can't run Dataframes chunks on R Notebook (Rstudio)

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

Anytime I try to check on a dataframe on a .Rmd file, RStudio won't run it. I can read the csv file, but when I call it, nothing happens. I can tell it's a problem with Dataframes because I can run mathematical equations and even plot some graphic.

[image]

When I open the .html file, saved using Knitr, it's all ok:

[image]

Comment: This is the expected behavior and works fine for me. Seems silly, but have you actually clicked on "Run current chunk" in that little "Run" dropdown menu?

Comment: Yes I did, it is only running in Console. I can turn it into a matrix using as.Matrix() and it will show me the table all right, but as a dataframe nothing happens Inline.